# making a chat app in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to make my first app in xcode using http://www.parse.com. I am pretty much copying [this guys](http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com) instructions and i'm getting and error when i start putting this code

```
PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
[testObject setObject:@"bar" forKey:@"foo"];
[testObject save];
```

in the FirstViewController.m file.

```
 #import "DMFirstViewController.h"
@interface DMFirstViewController ()
@end
@implementation DMFirstViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
    [testObject setObject:@"bar" forKey:@"foo"];
    [testObject save];  
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Can somebody please help me I will post the error after i post this. Let me know what other code you need me to post to help, thanks.

[image: Here is a pictures of my FirstViewController.m file with the error.]
[image: closer picture]

Comment: What kinds of errors are you getting?

Comment: It looks like you might not have linked the library.  Select your ChatTest project icon in the left pane, then select Summary, scroll down to 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' and add Parse.framework if its not there.

Comment: Parse.framework is there as required.

Comment: It says Unknown reciever "PFObject"; did you mean "NSObject"? I can post anything you want me to just ask.

Comment: I would assume that there's a "PFObject.h" file someplace that you should be importing.

Comment: not that i can find. but i just checked the demo from the github chat app i got the idea from, and there's not one in theirs either.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing this line

```
 #import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Everytime you use something starting with "PF" like PFObject, it an object used by the parse framework so you need to import the framework.